# XNA: only call rectangle intersection on the initial intersection

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection, intersection, rectangles

I am currently making a top down shooter in xna. I have managed to work around this constant problem quite a few times in the project but now I am programming the gameplay and It is screwing with my collisions. I want the players life to go down by just 1 if they make contact with the enemy, but if the rectangles intersect it is called at the refresh rate of the software (or however it is done now that I think about it) so the players lives actually go down by a few dozen for the second of intersection. Is there a way to stop this?

example code which isn't working:

```
            if (playerRectangle.Intersects(enemyRectangle))
            {
                enemyAlive = false;
                playerLives--;
            }
```

I know this seems simple but it has been messing with my game all week. Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your condition to this:

```
(playerRectangle.Intersects(enemyRectangle) && enemyAlive)
```

and that should do the trick for you.

EDIT: as Zhafur pointed out, there is a simple optimization that can be done:

```
(enemyAlive && playerRectangle.Intersects(enemyRectangle))
```

I would point out that the `Intersects` method must check all 4 sides of the player's rectangle with all 4 sides of the enemy's rectangle. This would then make this simple call something like 16 smaller checks. If someone knows that figure for certain, please correct me if I am wrong. Personally I would do something like this:

```
float playerSize = 16f; // These are the _radius_ not the diameter.
float enemySize = 16f;
```

Then replace the `Intersects` method in the condition with a call to `Vector2.Distance`:

```
(enemyAlive && (playerSize + enemySize >= Vector2.Distance(playerLocation, enemyLocation)))
```

Where playerLocation and enemyLocation represent the *center point* of the player and enemy.

Comment: I'd check the enemyAlive, and if it's true, then check if the two rectangles are intersecting or not. It would be more performance wise. :) +1

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much! that's perfect! I am a bit raging it was something so simple haha. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: @Zhafur: Agreed, but there are other means of handling this situation. I'll append an edit to reflect some optimizations.